# Is there a ready-made HTTP server for debugging purposes?

Tags: python, http, network-protocols

Today I found myself needing a simple HTTP server that would log/print out everything it knows about the request and respond with some dummy reply (for debugging). Surprisingly enough, I couldn't find any read to use tool for that - am I missing something?

Python's SimpleHTTPServer module looks promising, maybe there is a really quick way to just dump the whole request using it?

I need it to run locally.

Answer (score 8):

From some quick searches on google it looks like the easiest way to do this would be to sublcass SimpleHttpServer and log whatever it is you want to see.

This [looks](http://georgik.sinusgear.com/2011/01/07/how-to-dump-post-request-with-python/) to be very easy

```
class ServerHandler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        logging.error(self.headers)
        # whatever else you would like to log here
        SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)

Handler = ServerHandler

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

print "serving at port", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Additionally you can have your `do_GET` and `do_POST` return whatever 'dummy' reply you want.

Comment: is there a generic method to use for all types of requests?

Comment: $ /usr/bin/python3 -m http.server

Comment: Code in answer updated for python3: https://gist.github.com/jwhb/de4225afba72328af443671177666ec5

Answer (score 6):

```
ruby -r sinatra -e "get('/') { puts params.inspect }"
```

Documentation: http://www.sinatrarb.com

Ruby is simple and flexible and it allows you to mock any reply quickly.

Comment: --Answers a python question with ruby.-- Wat?

Answer (score 0):

[Turq](https://pypi.org/project/turq/) works well for this kind of purpose. It is written in Python, simple to use yet extensive, flexible and even has a GUI. Developers of Turq describe it thus:

> Turq is a small HTTP server that can be scripted in a Python-based
>   language. Use it to set up mock HTTP resources that respond with the
>   status, headers, and body of your choosing. Turq is designed for quick
>   interactive testing, but can be used in automated scenarios as well.

It also has [good documentation](https://turq.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Caveat: While Turq is perfectly useful, its author has stopped maintaining it, recommending [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org) instead; mitmproxy has a Python API too.

Answer (score 0):

Hi take a look at ReturnToSender on github, its a mock http server that runs locally. Not web hosted. Responds to http client with your mock data and displays client request details.

https://github.com/stephenhealey86/ReturnToSender

Supports GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE request types and JSON, TEXT, JavaScript, XML, HTML content types.